# Django custom form registration TypeError at /accounts/register register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

ImproperlyConfigured at /accounts/register

Could not create directory for saving email messages: /home/user/Desktop/emails ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user')

It points to this line "user.email_user(subject, message, html_message=message)" in views.register in account.

auth.html

```
<form id='registration-form' method='post' action={% url 'accounts:register' %}>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-upper" id="fullname" placeholder="John Doe" name="fullname" required><br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-upper" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username"><br>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control input-upper" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required><br>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input-upper" id="organization" placeholder="Organization" name="organization" required><br>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control input-upper" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password1" required><br>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control input-upper" id="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password2" required><br>
                      <small>By registering you agree to our <a href="{% url 'tos' %}">terms and conditions</a></small>
                      <button type="submit" value='register' id='reg-submit-btn' class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-signup-form">SIGN UP</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sign-linkedin" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'linkedin-oauth2' %}?next={{ next }}">Sign up with LinkedIn</button>
                      <p class="text-already">Already have an account? <a href="" >LOGIN</a></p>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

MOdel Userprofile.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """ Profile for the User Model """

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='profile',
        verbose_name='other Details',
    )
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    organization = models.CharField(default='', max_length=300, blank=True)
    referral = models.OneToOneField(
        Referral, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='profile', verbose_name='profile Details',
        null=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + '\'s profile'

    def activate(self):
        """" Activates account after email is confirmed """

        self.email_confirmed = True
        self.user.is_active = True
        self.save()
        self.user.save()
```

Views.py

```
@transaction.atomic
def register(request):
    """Process registration of new users"""
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'loggedin'})
    status = dict()
    status['status'] = 'failure'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save Profile details
            user = form.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'DHIS2 Account Activation'
            message = render_to_string(
                'registration/account_activation_email.html',
                {
                    'user': user,
                    'domain': current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(
                        force_bytes(
                            user.pk)).decode(),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                },
                request=request)
            user.email_user(subject, message, html_message=message)
            Referral.record_response(request, "REGISTERED")
            #return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
            return redirect('accounts:account_activation_sent')
        status = form.errors
        status['status'] = 'failure'
    return JsonResponse(status)
```

I get a json response of status:Failure, and password1: "This field is required." and password2:"This field is required.
What could I be doing wrong? Probably the template doesn't save or something. How do i make a custom django form that makes use of the html template.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have fields with names `password1` and `password2` in your template; you just have two fields named `password`. You need to give them the correct `name` attributes.

Comment: I changed the html fields to password1 and the other to password2, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Where do you get that error? Show the full traceback. And show your URL.

Comment: Sorry, I still get the password1 and password2: This field is required after changing the auth.html password id to password1 & password2....Is that how I am suppose to do that? I''m new to django

Comment: You need to change the `name` attributes, not the `id`.

Comment: I did that but now I am getting a json response that says status:failure

Comment: I get this error now Could not create directory for saving email messages: /home/user/Desktop/emails ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user')
Exception Location: